# How can I prevent Chrome's console from condensing characters and print each one?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

My function (code below) transposes 2 strings provided in an array, logging the words in a vertical direction. The issue I have is that the 2 m's in the word, 'programmer' and the 2 l's in 'Hello' are condensed and you can see the number 2 to their left.

How can I get the console to show me each 'm' and 'l'. Why does this only happen when one of the strings is shorter than the other?

I ran it on https://jsfiddle.net/ but I don't this affects the output.

[image: Image of Output]

```
function transposeTwoStrings(arr)
{

    // split into characters
    var arr1 = arr[0].split('');
  var arr2 = arr[1].split('');

  //figure out longer array
  // since we will be pushing values, we will be changing the length, so
  // shouldn't use length property

  var length1 = arr1.length;
  var length2 = arr2.length;
  var diff;
  var longer;

  if (length1 > length2)
  {
    longer = length1;
    diff = length1 - length2;
    for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++)
    {
      arr2.push(' ');
    }
  }
  else if (length1 < length2)
  {
    longer = length2
    diff = length2 - length1;
    for (var k = 0; k < diff; k++)
    {
      arr1.push(' ');
    }
  }
  else
  {
    longer = length1;
  }
  //log values
  for (var j = 0; j < longer; j++)
  {
    console.log(arr1[j] + ' ' + arr2[j]);
  }


}

var arr1 = ['Hello', 'World'];
var arr2 = ['Hello', 'Jo'];
var arr3 = ['Jo', 'Hello'];
var arr4 = ['We are', 'programmers.']

transposeTwoStrings(arr1);
console.log('--------');
transposeTwoStrings(arr2);
console.log('--------');
transposeTwoStrings(arr3);
console.log('--------');
transposeTwoStrings(arr4);
console.log('--------');
```

Answer (score 2):

See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ for a lots of settings. 
There you can see one solution:

> If you prefer a unique line entry for every log, enable Show
>   timestamps from the DevTools settings. Since the timestamp of each
>   message is different, each message is displayed on its own line.

Now you have the timestamp on each line, but no "condensed" lines.

Comment: This solution works but it takes up horizontal space of the output when I would like to see only things that matter on my small screen. Is there a way of doing it without the timestamp?

Comment: `Is there a way of doing it without the timestamp?` It's shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the strings are equal.
Add a space character to every second string:

```
for (var j = 0; j < longer; j++) {
  console.log(arr1[j] + ' ' + arr2[j] + (j%2 ? ' ' : ''));
}
```

Ideally, check if the last output is equal to the current one and add the space for every second copy.

Comment: Are you saying that this is a JavaScript thing and not one related to the console?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that.

Comment: Then, why would I need to change the code? If you look at the first example , 'Hello World' is logged with both L's  visible.

Comment: The lines are different in hello world: `l r` and `l l` whereas the collapsed output lines are identical.